# Parallax scrolling bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i've got a problem with my site, my problem is: When I'm scrolling down on my page [(here is the link)](http://nagyattila.esy.es/theme1) and I reach the bottom of the page I see, the footer is not at the bottom on the page. I know the error is that, the bootsrtap's carousel on the top is get a parallax effect when I scroll. And I made this parallax effect with jquery & css3 transform:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($('html').width() > 767) { //For mobile devices
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('.parallax').css({
            'transform': 'translate(0px, -' + (top / 500) + 'px)'
        });
        $('.parallax + section').css({
            'transform': 'translate(0px, -' + top + 'px)'
        });
        console.log('A parallax effect működik... top: ' + top);
    }
});
```

So the section in body is translaing up, but the body's height isn't change dinamically.
So this is my prblem.

Answer (score 1):

Your js(scripts) at the bottom need to be inside the body(element) closing tag not outside.

Here is a parallax framework in pure CSS no JS which makes it extremely faster performance wise: http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/demo3/